# Send message with multiple local images in a single line - discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Is this possible to send messages with multiple local images in a single line?

I'm using `MessageAttachment` here is the code

> const attachment = new MessageAttachment(EmojiPack1/green/g_a.png)
>
> message.reply({files: [attachment]})

I'm using it in a `for loop` But it sends a message with the line breaker

Can you please guide me on how to make it a single message of a single line having multiple images?

[image]

Have to make it in a single line.
like this
[image]
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to send images inline, instead you should use custom emojis.

You can use a private server for the bot that has all these letters as custom emojis. Then to get the emoji string put a backslash in front of it to get a string like this: `<a:THIS:930734808169086986>`

Comment: Can you please tell me from where I can get those alphabet emoji from discord

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternate solution. Discord also has their own alphabet emojis though. :regional_indicator_a:, :regional_indicator_b: and so on

Comment: yes, but I need alphabetic emojis in 4 different colors -> gray, green, red & yellow

Comment: then the solution that I mentioned in my answer should work just fine

Comment: Or there is another way you where I can use my local images in a message or embed in a inline form?

Comment: Not to my knowledge but even if it's possible it would most likely get plagued by line wrapping. Just having an emoji server for your bot and then use the emojis from that servers is most likely the easiest solution

Comment: but they are like 26 * 4 -> 104 emojis, discord allows only 50 emojis per server.

Comment: check the new edit. Someone did it but didn't know how.

Comment: They are using the initial emoji approach that I gave you.

Comment: Yes I understand that, But the problem is its limited to 50 emojis I need 104 :(